# Setting a new line in this function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
function setLineDelay(delay, str) {
  var lines = str.split('_');
  $.each(lines, function(index, h) {
    var div = $('<div class=\'question_item\'/>').html(h);
    div.hide().appendTo('#question_wrapper').delay(index * delay);
    setTimeout(function() {
      div.fadeIn();
    }, index * delay);
  });
}


setLineDelay(500,"I am a:" + "<h1>" + " _ J_avascript<h1> _ E_mulated<br /> _ S_erialized<br /> _ I_ntelligence\n _ created by Matt._ <br /> But, you can call me Jesi for short._ <br /> And your name is?...");
```

I have tried everything. I have tried:

```
<h1>, <br>, <br />, \n
```

I am trying to get a new line in the function, but it always ignores the "new line functions", for example, \n.

Example website: http://lyndoncis.com/CIS3120SP16/mts01060/

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bgLnvzu0/1/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its a thing, but you are missing the closing tag on the  tag. Should it should be?

```
"<h1>" + " _ J_avascript</h1>...
```

might be causing a problem

Comment: I don't think if that is an issue, as HTML is intelligent enough to close it. Even if a heading has line-breaks it will do it. One can try in the jsfiddle or other.

Comment: except that it will close the first h1 as follows:<h1>" + " _ J_avascript</h1> and then will take the incorrct <h1> as the starting tag and lump all following characters into it and close it at the end - meaning there will be a second <h1>all remaining content</h1> listed.

Comment: You can refer to the jsfiddle provided by 'Arun P Johny' in the comments section of the question.